# Connection to SQL Server through ADO.NET - Empty Listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-express

Trying to set up a connection to my local SQL Server Express instance so that I can display columns in a listbox. Th build runs fine and I can't see errors, but there is no data in the listbox. I have tested the query and that is fine. I am using NT Authentication to the database. Any ideas where I might have gone wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string commstring = "Driver ={SQL Server}; Server = DESKTOP-5T4MHHR\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = AdventureWorks2014; Trusted_Connection = Yes;";
        string connstring = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Person";

        SqlDataAdapter customerDataAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter(commstring, connstring);

        DataSet customerDataSet = new DataSet();
        customerDataAdapater.Fill(customerDataSet, "Person.Person");

        DataTable customerDataTable = new DataTable();
        customerDataTable = customerDataSet.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in customerDataTable.Rows)
        {
            customers.Items.Add(dataRow["FirstName"] + " (" + dataRow["LastName"] + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Database is **AdventureWorks2014**, but you use **Person.Person**. How? That should be **AdventureWorks2014.Person**.

Comment: @BerkayYaylaci there's nothing wrong with the table name, the OP is specifyint the table's schema. In fact, `AdventureWorks2014.Person` would be wrong, you'd have to type `AdventureWorks2014.dbo.Person`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, good point.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: and `AdventureWorks2014.dbo.Person` would be **wrong**, too, since the `Person` table is in the `Person` schema, so it would have to be: `AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person`

Comment: @marc_s sorry, I've already moved to Worldwide importers! Seriously, that's what I meant. If `Person` was in `dbo`, using `AdventureWorks2014.Person` would fail. The OP would have to use `AdventureWorks2014.dbo.Person` or just `Person`

Comment: Check the constructor parameters orders. It seems you have passed the command text as connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in a sample project here and I realized you passed the parameters to SqlDataAdapter constructor in a wrong order.

After changing the follow line:

```
SqlDataAdapter customerDataAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter(commstring, connstring);
```

by

```
SqlDataAdapter customerDataAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter(connstring, commstring);
```

the listbox was filled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string seems weird.....

Could you try using just this:

```
string commstring = "Server=DESKTOP-5T4MHHR\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks2014;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
```

Also: why are you first creating a `DataSet`, filling in a single set of data, and then extracting a `DataTable` from it?? This is unnecessarily complicated code - just use this instead:

```
SqlDataAdapter customerDataAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter(commstring, connstring);

// if you only ever need *one* set of data - just use a DataTable directly!
DataTable customerDataTable = new DataTable();

// Fill DataTable with the data from the query
customerDataAdapater.Fill(customerDataTable);
```

**Update:** I would really rewrite your code to something like this:

```
// create a separate class - call it whatever you like
public class DataProvider
{
    // define a method to provide that data to you
    public List<string> GetPeople()
    {
        // define connection string (I'd really load that from CONFIG, in real world)
        string connstring = "Server=MSEDTOP;Database=AdventureWorks2014;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

        // define your query
        string query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Person";

        // prepare a variable to hold the results
        List<string> entries = new List<string>();

        // put your SqlConnection and SqlCommand into "using" blocks
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // iterate over the results using a SqlDataReader
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    // get first and last name from current row of query
                    string firstName = rdr.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
                    string lastName = rdr.GetFieldValue<string>(1);

                    // add entry to result list
                    entries.Add(firstName + " " + lastName);
                }

                rdr.Close();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        // return the results
        return entries;
    }
}
```

And in your code-behind, you only need to do something like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(.....)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        List<string> people = new DataProvider().GetPeople();

        customers.DataSource = people;
        customers.DataBind();
    }
}
```

but I still don't understand what you were trying to when the *SelectedIndexChanged* event happens.....

Comment: Thanks for showing me a simpler way. I have tried the above but it is still blank. Any ideas?

Comment: So I also added a try catch to a button which when pressed opens the sql connection and if successful it shows a message box saying as much and this has worked. So it is able to connect. The connection string is fine. Is is the query? Tried multiple tables and still getting nothing

Comment: @NickProud: what I don't quite understand is what you're really trying to accomplish.... every time you change the selection of your `customers` listbox, you go out and get all the data again....... seems a bit overkill. What are you **really** trying to do??

Comment: @NickProud: I tried your code (not in a listbox scenario, but just the raw query) - it works just fine. There's something else going on here....